# Angular JS separated controllers to files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In each tutorial focusing on the AngularJS I saw that all controllers was in one file controllers.js.

I think, that more practical is have to controllers in separated files.

**Question is:**

how can i create separated controllers in AngularJS?
How to put controller CRUD methods inside the Controller (to have structure like this)?

```
Controller Users
 - method get 
 - method add 
 - method edit
 - method delete
```

Thanks for any help and example how to.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this approch (see example below)

Javascript:

```
// first file, must be include in first in your HTML
var example = angular.module('example', []);

example.factory('IndexModel', function() {
  return {
    get: function() {
      return 'index controller';
    }
  };
});

example.controller('Index', function($scope, IndexModel) {
  $scope.name = IndexModel.get();
});

// other file
var example = angular.module('example'); // angular module is accessible like this

example.factory('UserModel', function() {
  return {
    get: function() {
      return 'user controller';
    }
  }
});

example.controller('User', function($scope, UserModel) {
  $scope.name = UserModel.get();
});
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bAvEl

Comment: or just start each controller file with: angular.module('example').controller('whatever', whateverControllerFunction);

Answer (score 0):

```
 angular.module('controllers', []);
```

Add this on your angular app initialization code, then in each controller file just something like the following (and obvs reference the script file in html) :

```
(function() {
  angular.module('controllers').controller('UserController', function($scope, $http) {
    // your crud methods
    $http.get('your-user-rest-url').success(function(result) {
      return $scope.user = result;
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```